Brightness Controller not working ubuntu 24.04.1
As the title reads my brightness controller even on sliding is not working i applied all the solutions available online but to no avail. Originally there was no brightness controller slider present but now there seems to be one but it still is not working.

Can you edit your question with some hardware details?
